# Stopping a Thrift server(TSimpleServer)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thrift

I have a simple use case for a Thrift Server(`TSimpleServer`) wherein I have a couple of threads spawned(besides the main thread). One of the newly spawned threads enters the Thrift event loop (i.e `server.serve()`). Upon receiving a signal in the main thread I invoke `server.stop()` which is causing the error posted below.

At first I thought it was an uncaught exception. However wrapping both the invocations of `server.serve()` and `server.stop()` in `try-catch`'es didn't help isolate the problem. Any thoughts/suggestions(on what I should be doing)? Most Thrift tutorials/guides/examples seem to talk about server start but don't seem to mention the stop scenario, any pointers/best-practices/suggestions in this regard would be great. Thanks.

Also, I am using thrift-0.7.0.

Error details:

```
Thrift: Fri Nov 18 21:22:47 2011 TServerTransport died on accept: TTransportExc\
eption: Interrupted
*** glibc detected *** ./build/mc_daemon: munmap_chunk(): invalid poi\
nter: 0x0000000000695f18 ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also here's the stack-trace:

```
#0  0x00007fb751c92f08 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fb7524bb0eb in apache::thrift::server::TSimpleServer::serve (
    this=0x1e5bca0) at src/server/TSimpleServer.cpp:140
#2  0x000000000046ce15 in a::b::server_thread::operator() (
    this=0x695f18)
    at /path/to/server_thread.cpp:80
#3  0x000000000046c1a9 in boost::detail::thread_data<boost::reference_wrapper<a\
ds::data_load::server_thread> >::run (this=0x1e5bd80)
    at /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:81
#4  0x00007fb7526f2b70 in thread_proxy ()
   from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.40.0
#5  0x00007fb7516fd9ca in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007fb7519fa70d in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Edit 1: I have added pseudo-code for the [main thread](http://pastebin.com/CqNgLxnf), the [thrift server thread](http://pastebin.com/ZKVTUDeq) and the [background thread](http://pastebin.com/67r7vwEW).

Edit 2: I seem to have resolved the original issue as noted in my answer below. However this solution leads to two rather undesirable/questionable design choices: (i) I had to introduce a thrift endpoint to enable a mechanism to stop the server (ii) The handler class for the thrift service(which is usually required to instantiate a server object) now requires a means to signal back to the server to stop, introducing a circular dependency of sorts.

Any suggestions on these design issues/choices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like memory corruption. How is your signal handler coded?

Comment: The signal handler sets a flag which is being monitored by the main thread. On being set, the main thread calls stop on the server instance(which is running in another thread). Not sure if this is a no-no, multi-threading + thrift neophyte here.

Comment: please update your question with the signal handler code, it would also be beneficial if you can post a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Per your suggestion I added links to pastebins of pseudo-code for the main, thrift server and background threads. At this time I seem to have resolved the original problem I was facing and had some Thrift related design questions, which I have added to the question as well(see Edit 2). It would be great if you could chime in on those. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem seems to have stemmed from my code/design wherein I had signal-handler code in the main thread invoking `stop` on the server which was started in a 'server thread'. Changing this behavior(as noted in the pastebin code-snippets) helped resolve this issue.