# How exactly does TSimpleServer .serve() work?

Tags: thrift

I am trying to improve my base understanding of how setting up a thrift server with TSimpleServer works.  Mainly regarding starting/stopping.

I am using TSimpleServer, which I understand to be simple singlethreaded server mostly for deubgging.  My immediate questions here are does singlethreaded here mean:

a.)  calling TSimpleServer spawns a single thread that can handle only 1 client connection at a time, but simultaneously returns execution back to the main program calling .serve to continue?
or
  b.)  calling TSimpleServer.serve() blocks until the server is stopped.

If b.), what is the mechanism to stop the server?  most of what I've researched, suggests stopping the server from a different thread then the one that started it will cause a crash.  (see: [Stopping a Thrift server(TSimpleServer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191488/stopping-a-thrift-servertsimpleserver)).   That would imply to me a.) is correct answer above, else there is circular logic somewhere?

edit:  I have managed to convince myself it is in fact b.  but the question remains given the above-referenced post,  even if I spawn a new thread to start it, and that thread blocks,  how do I stop it?  using a different thread seems not to be an answer from the above referenced post

Answer (score 0):

On [thrift API documentation](http://people.apache.org/~jfarrell/thrift/0.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TServer.html#stop%28%29) (Java) you can read:

> Stop the server. This is optional on a per-implementation basis. Not all servers are required to be cleanly stoppable.

TSimpleServer is used in testing. So, is it possible that there is no clean way of doing it?